# Django template includes slow?

Tags: django, django-templates

Should I be trying to minimize template includes? I've been using them somewhat liberally but am wondering if they are inefficient or add some overhead in rendering templates?

In some cases I have templates that include templates which include other templates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Template rendering time is normally much smaller than database time in especial, so typically you don't need to worry about it early on; there are other regions where performance can be increased more effectively.

For deployment, you can usually increase the performance of template inclusions by using [the cached loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) (you may need to scroll down a bit). Then it only loads templates once and thereafter it can use the compiled template instead of needing to load it from disk.

To address the question of template rendering overhead, once you've got it cached, it's quite cheap. I wouldn't worry about it at all. Do it in such as way as to maximise the maintainability of your system.

It would probably be irresponsible of me to not mention (hopefully, remind you of) two adages of performance optimisation; they are common enough sayings that you should be able to find plenty of information on them if you are not familiar with them.

1. Don't optimise prematurely.
2. Measure—don't guess.

Comment: Ive been using django for 2 years now, and never managed to read about the cached loader. Thank you. Alas, I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: @zsquare: it's certainly not given the prominence that I think it deserves. I only found it because I was doing a particular non-web thing where I was rendering several templates around five thousand times each in succession and knew that there *must* be a way of caching them, that people *must* have had the need before---and even then I didn't find it in the docs immediately but found it via a ticket in the bug tracker.

Comment: Django's templates are extraordinarily slow, and it's not true that the database is usually the bottleneck, just in some cases. That principle is simply a dogma. When I run `ab` on a page with 7 typical queries (a few joins, 1 `COUNT`, no aggregation, etc.) to Postgres and 20 template includes (using the cached loader), and render the same template with 0 includes (include the same output inline) in a template, I go from 48 requests per second to 8 requests per second (`ab -n 1000 -c 4 [url]`) - 4 workers with uWSGI on a quad core with 8GB of RAM, zero HD IO, except for the database.

Comment: Interesting (re: single threaded), thanks. Also, I made a mistake; the VirtualBox that I was running Django in only had 1GB of RAM allocated to it. I maintain that template inclusion is extremely slow, and that it's a very heavily used feature in most apps I've worked on, but admit that 20 includes is a bit much. Most of my templates have only 3-6 includes.

Comment: Does calling model methods also count as template inclusion?? I am not very sure so wanted to know.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra: no. What's being queried here is just templates including other templates with `{% include %}`.